# Kotlin Anko textview id

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

tengo una consulta.

Estoy trabajando con Kotlin y Anko para hacer una vista desde el código.

Los datos de las columnas no los conozco de antemano, por lo tanto tengo que hacer el código de tal forma de generar los textview y edittext con los datos de una tabla que tengo en el dispositivo, pero sin saber el nombre de la columna ni el dato.

Eso lo tengo resuelto.

El problema me surge cuando deseo colocarle un ID al elemento para luego (en el botón de guardar) poder capturar el valor que tiene en ese momento y asignarselo a una variable para actualizar la tabla

El código en donde genero los elementos visuales son los siguientes

```
for (col in columnNames)
                    {
                        if (col == "Observaciones" || col == "Domicilio"){
                            linearLayout {
                                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(matchParent, matchParent)
                                padding = dip(5)
                                this.gravity = Gravity.START
                                weightSum = 1.0f

                                textView {
                                    text = "$col"
                                    textSize = 20f
                                    textColor = Color.BLACK
                                    textAlignment =
                                        View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START //CENTER can be INHERIT GRAVITY TEXT_START TEXT_END VIEW_START VIEW_END
                                }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent) {
                                    marginEnd = 5
                                }
                            }

                            linearLayout {
                                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(matchParent, matchParent)
                                padding = dip(5)
                                this.gravity = Gravity.START
                                weightSum = 1.0f

                                editText {
                                    hint = "$value"
                                    gravity = Gravity.END
                                    textSize = 18f
                                    isEnabled = estate
                                    textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START
                                }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
                                {
                                    weight = 0.7f
                                }
                            }
```

En el editText por ejemplo debería colocarle un ID identificatorio para luego, como lo mencione, capturar el valor y guardarlo. En alguna documentación e visto "R.id.xxx" pero en mi caso esto no es posible ya que no tengo ningún elemento gráfico creado

Coloco ID = "$col" y me da error

Cual sería la manera correcta de hacerlo? o como hago en el botón "Guardar" para llamar a un elemento sin asignarle un ID?

GRACIAS !!!

Lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al intentar colocar un texto me dice que necesita un Int

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Existen dos formas que puedes solucionar tu problema.
Primero ahi dice claramente que error tienes. Estas asignando un String a un atributo que recibe un Int.
Podrias colocarle la posición de la columna u otro entero.

Otra solución es no asignarle el ID, y solo guardar el elemento en un Array,
Un Array de EditText, para que cuando quieras guardar, recuperes de todos los EditText que creaste.